# Template in D programming

Tags: d

Can someone explain the code below? I get confused when I try to understand how isNumeric!T works in this case.

```
auto foo(T)(T n) if (isNumeric!T) {
     return (T m) {return m > n;};
}

void main() {
    auto hoo5 = foo!int(1000);
    writeln(hoo5(93));
    writeln(hoo5(23));
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start with:

```
auto foo(T)(T n) if (isNumeric!T) {
     // ignore this for now
}
```

foo is a generic function that takes one argument of its generic type. `if (isNumeric!T)` is a compile-time check from [std.traits](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_traits.html#isNumeric) that guarantees foo's type is numeric. Non-numeric types won't work. Its return type is inferred and in this case is a delegate.

This:

```
(T m) {return m > n;}; //returned from foo
```

is a [delegate literal](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/expression.html#FunctionLiteral) ([or closure](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/function.html#closures)). It's basically a function pointer with state. In this case, it closes over the parameter `n` passed to foo. In your example:

```
auto hoo5 = foo!int(1000);
```

is effectively translated to the function:

```
bool hoo5 (int x) { return x > 1000; }
```

So when you call `hoo5`, it returns a boolean indicating if its argument is greater than 1000 - but only in your specific case.

If you call foo like this:

```
auto hoo5 = foo!double(1.2345);
```

You get a reference to a function that returns a boolean indicating if its argument (a double) is greater than 1.2345.

Comment: There are typos. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: You explain really well. I understand it now. Thank you.